# Trouble printing text live with Python subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

Off the bat, here is what I am importing:
    import os, shutil
    from subprocess import call, PIPE, STDOUT

I have a line of code that calls bjam to compile a library:

```
call(['./bjam',
      '-j8',
      '--prefix="' + tools_dir + '"'],
     stdout=PIPE)
```

I want it to print out text as the compilation occurs. Instead, it prints everything out at the end.

It does not print anything when I run it like this. I have tried running the command outside of Python and determined that all of the output is to stdout (when I did `./bjam -j8 > /dev/null` I got no output, and when I ran `./bjam -j8 2> /dev/null` I got output).

What am I doing wrong here? I want to print the output from call live.

---

As a sidenote, I also noticed something when I was outputting the results of a git clone operation:

```
call(['git',
      'clone', 'https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder.git'],
     stdout=PIPE)
```

prints the stdout text live as the call process is run.

```
call(['git',
      'clone', 'https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder.git'],
     stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

does not print out any text. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def run(command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for lineno, line in enumerate(proc.stdout):
        try:
            print(line.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', ''))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print('error(%d): cannot decode %s' % (lineno, line))
```

The `try...except` logic is for python 3 (maybe 3.2/3.3, I'm not sure), as there `line` is a byte array not a string. For earlier versions of python, you should be able to do:

```
def run(command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line.replace('\n', ''))
```

Now, you can do:

```
run(['./bjam', '-j8', '--prefix="' + tools_dir + '"'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`stdout=PIPE` redirects subprocess' stdout to a pipe. Don't do it unless you want to read from the subprocesses stdout in your code using `proc.communicate()` method or using `proc.stdout` attribute directly.

If you remove it then subprocess should print to stdout like it does in the shell:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(['./bjam', '-j8', '--prefix', tools_dir])
```

I've used `check_call()` to raise an exception if the child process fails.

See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279) if you want to read subprocess' output line by line (making the line available as a variable in Python) as soon as it is avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

`call` will not print anything it captures. As [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) says "Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer."

Consider using `check_output` and print its return value.

In the first case with git call you are not capturing `stderr` and therefor it normally flows onto your terminal.